# dependentAssembly with duplicate assemblyIdentity, how will it handle in this case?

Tags: asp.net, .net, config, assembly-binding-redirect

I've just found that somehow in my `Web.config` has the 2 followings:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
...
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

So I wonder how it will redirect a required assembly of `Newtonsoft.Json` with version from `0` to `7.0`? The result is `7.0` or `10.0`? Also it's strange that the `publicKeyToken` for the first is capitalized whereas the second's is just normal.